# What does $\mathbb{R}^2$ domain mean?

Tags: graphing-functions, parametric

I have a parametric curve defined by :

$\gamma\colon\left[ 0,+\infty \right] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined:
$\gamma(t) = (\ln(t), 3\cdot\ln(6t))$

Now I have to say if the plot of this curve is a line of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and explain why. I don't know what $\mathbb{R}^2$ means, so I can't answer the question. Can anyone help?

Comment: $\Bbb R^2$ is the common $xy$-plane. That is probably what $R^2$ means as well.

Comment: Yeah I edited just after, thanks :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition: $$\Bbb R^2 := \Bbb R \times \Bbb R = \{(x,y) \mid x,y \in \Bbb R\},$$ that is, the euclidean plane that you're used to, in doing analytic geometry, graphing functions, etc.

For your exercise, call $x(t) = \ln t$ and $y(t) = 3 \ln (6t)$. Use properties of $\ln$ and eliminate $t$ from these relations, get $y$ as a function of $x$. You'll see something familiar.

Comment: It has to be proved. Calling the components $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ does not make it a line. Take for example $x(t) = \cos t$, $y(t) = \sin t$.

Comment: I get $y(t) = 3*ln(6)+x(t)$. It's a linear line so I'd say it's true.

Comment: That's right! Although ugly, $3\ln 6$ is just a constant, so you got $y = a+bx$, a line.

Comment: Yeah of course I'm gonna write that well, thanks for the help. As usual, "you just have to think about it" :p.

Comment: Don't mind it, glad to help. If you manage to write it well, you can always accept the answer (green checkmark) to take the question out of the unanswered list. It helps organizing the site . If you still need any push, just say it (:

Comment: Yeah I'm used to the website (more to stackoverflow but same thing), just was writing the answer :).

Comment: I'm wondering: you get $y(t) = a + bx(t)$ with $x(t) = ln(t)$ so it's not a linear function, is it ?

Comment: $y$ is a linear function of $x$, **not** of $t$.

Comment: Yes that's what I just saw afterwards, sorry :p.